# Launch "Software Boutique" from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, root, mate, software-boutique

I need to run the Software Boutique as a superuser.
How can I run the Software Boutique from the terminal?

Comment: Hi TomKivy, *if* an answer fully addresses your question, please consider accepting it (tick the big V).  It is the appropriate way to indicate an answer works for you and gives clarity to possible other users with the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Software Boutique is an application specific to MATE desktop; it's actually part of the **welcome** app.

The command to run the Boutique is `ubuntu-mate-welcome --boutique` so to launch as root I would run (in Ubuntu MATE 16.10):

```
sudo -i
ubuntu-mate-welcome --boutique
```

when done, be sure to type `exit` in the terminal to drop root privileges.